# how to combine 2 array of array to array of object

Tags: php

This is the return result of my two variables:

```
$resultPayment = [
    [72875500, 8187000],
    [14343],
    [44419200,
    ["12332000"],
    [28700250]
  ]
$resultId = [
    ["461", "462"],
    [6462],
    [8771],
    [8461],
    [5461]
]
```

This is the code for get the data:

```
for ($iii=0; $iii<count($dataInvoice); $iii++) {
      $resultId[] = unserialize($dataInvoice[$iii]->invoiceid);
      $resultPayment[] = unserialize($dataInvoice[$iii]->jumlahbayarid);
}
```

These two pieces of data are the same length and array structure, and I want to combine `$id` and `$payment` and create an object. Here are the results I expect :

```
[
    { "461": 72875500 },
    { "462": 8187000 },
    { 6462: 14343 },
    { 8771: 44419200 },
    { 8461: "12332000" },
    { 5461: 28700250 }
]
```

Comment: Have a look at [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Comment: Do you want to keep the values as text and integers (`"461"`, `"462"`, `6462`, ...)?

Comment: No Mr. @Zhorov , i want to change to number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is the following example:

```
<?php

$payment = [
    [72875500, 8187000],
    [14343],
    [44419200],
    ["12332000"],
    [28700250]
];
$id = [
    ["461", "462"],
    [6462],
    [8771],
    [8461],
    [5461]
];

$payment = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $payment);
$id      = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $id);
$result  = json_encode(array(array_combine($id, $payment)));

echo $result;
?>
```

Result:

```
[{"461":72875500,"462":8187000,"6462":14343,"8771":44419200,"8461":"12332000","5461":28700250}]
```